# How to use non ASCII chars

Tags: unicode, listingsutf8

How to compile a `tex` file with this kind of chars (note that they have the same width): `██╗███████╗█`

I tried to find about non ASCII chars but no success (I found no related with this chars).

Comment: Package pmboxdraw

Comment: @egreg, thanks. I didn't know about that package. I am checking its documentation. I'm afraid it is not possible to insert directly the chars, but only using commands for each one!! I have a kind of logo created with this kind of chars, around 200 chars! Thanks.

Comment: No, with `inputenc` you can input directly the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pmboxdraw` together with `inputenc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}

██╗███████╗█

\begin{verbatim}
╔╗
╚╝
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. But black and outlined don't have the same width?!

Comment: @Sigur Ask Heiko.

Comment: Dear @egreg, I got an answer from Heiko. To make black box with same width just use `\pmboxdrawsetup{Block/box/default=\strut0}`.

Comment: @Sigur Interesting! I should have read the documentation.

Comment: Now I found `\pmboxdrawsetup` on page 12 od documentation, but before I tried to read but no mention to it in the doc, only in the code part. So how could we guess?!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to embed SQLITE box mode (.mode box) outputs, the this is the complete list:

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces,
  literate=
  {┌}{\textSFi}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  {│}{\textSFxi}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  {└}{\textSFii}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  {┐}{\textSFiii}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  {┘}{\textSFiv}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  {┴}{\textSFvii}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  {┬}{\textSFvi}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  {├}{\textSFviii}{1}%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  {┤}{\textSFix}{1}%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  {─}{\textSFx}1%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  {┼}{\textSFv}1,
}
```